# Why is $e^{-ax}u(x)$ not continuous for $a\in\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Let $a\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\Re(a)>0$

Define the unit step function :
$$
u(x):=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $x\geq0$}\\
0&\text{if otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
We wish to study continuity of : $$f(x)=\frac{x^{k}}{k!}e^{-ax}u(x)$$
But I am only concerned regarding the case $k=0$ where we get $e^{-ax}u(x)$, with $a\in\mathbb{C}$ this would "virtually" mean that we have a decaying exponential multiplied with a complex sinusoidal but why would this imply that $f$ is not continuous for $k=0$? My textbook says $f$ must be continuous for all $k\geq1$

Comment: It it possible that you are having a moment of confusion and thinking that $e^{0}$ is $0$ instead of $1$?

Comment: I maybe having one large mental hiccup but let's hope not, All I see is $\frac{x^{0}}{0!}e^{-ax}u(x)\implies e^{-ax}$ if $x\geq0$ @MikeF

Comment: What is the domain of $f(x)$?

Comment: The domain as it appears is strictly dependent on the unit step function.

Comment: Yes, so the domain is all of $\Bbb R$, not just $\{x\ge 0\}$.

Comment: Indeed but I was thinking about $k=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $k=0$ the term $x^k$ vanishes and thats the one that guarantees continuity at zero, so the discontinuity of $u$ at $0$ comes into play.
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} e^{-ax}u(x)=0\neq 1 = f(0).$$

Comment: Ahh now I see thank you